# lxml - root.xpath() is returning HtmlElements with \r replaced with &#13; what are the best practices in dealing with this?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

The following code prints a bunch of unwanted `&#13;` entities within the HTML

```
import lxml.html
page = lxml.html.parse('http://www.crutchfield.com/m_247250/Satellite-Radio.html?tp=11').getroot()
category = page.xpath("//*[text()='By Category']/following-sibling::div[1]")[0]
print lxml.html.tostring(category)
```

all `\r`'s are being replaced with `&#13;` inside `page.xpath(..)`.  `page` itself doesn't have any issues though:

```
import lxml.html
page = lxml.html.parse('http://www.crutchfield.com/m_247250/Satellite-Radio.html?tp=11').getroot()
print lxml.html.tostring(page)
```

filtering out the '\r's prior to building our lxml.html.Element works fine, however I'm more interested best-practices for dealing with "type of problem" if it's generalizable enough.

Comment: Take a look at http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html

Comment: A correct HTML parser will treat the character entity `&#13` in the same way as the literal character.  Is this entity causing you problems in any particular context?  You should be able to ignore it.  See Also: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#line-breaks